# How get folder size in java

Tags: java

I want get folder size and Rename it,
if my folder size is more than 500 mbs then rename the folder, Download to MusicDownload

```
import java.io.File;

class folderSize {
    private static long getFolderSize(File folder)
    {
        long length = 0;
        File[] files = folder.listFiles();
        int count = files.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            if (files[i].isFile()) 
              length += files[i].length();
            }
            else {
                length += getFolderSize(files[i]);
            }
        }
        return length;
   }
    public static void main(String[] args)

    {
        File file1 = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Download");
        long size = getFolderSize(file1);
        System.out.println("Size of " + file1 + " is "+ (long)size / (1024 * 1024)+ " MB");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you. You told us what you want, and you dumped some code. But what is your exact problem/question?

Comment: The paths suggest you are talking about Android. Android is quite special when it comes to file I/O (mostly permissions) compared to "normal" Java. You should really edit your question to add that tag if appropriate and explain what specifically the problem is and where you need help.

Answer (score 0):

if You are using java8, can get the directory size as below

```
     long size = 0;
      try (Stream<Path> walk = Files.walk(pathOfDirectory)) {

          size = walk
                  .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
                  .mapToLong(p -> {
                      try {
                          return Files.size(p);
                      } catch (IOException e) {
                          System.out.printf("Failed to get size of %s%n%s", p, e);
                          return 0L;
                      }
                  })
                  .sum();

      } catch (IOException e) {
          System.out.printf("IO errors %s", e);
      }
```